# Print > Save as PDF - Saved to Google Docs, not local drive

Tags: google-chrome, google-docs, print-to-pdf, google-drive

Recently I gave the **Print > Save to Google Drive** option in Chome, and it works well. All my web-pages I use goes to my Google Drive account as PDF files.

My problem is, whenever I use the **Save as PDF** option, it saves them on Google Drive, not on my local drive!

How can I get back the capability of saving webpages to PDF files on my local drive?

Answer (score 1):

Saving as PDF should offer you the option of where you would like to save it on your local machine.  Click change, and choose save to PDF again, and then save.  If the save dialog does pop up again, verify the save location, and make sure it isn't your Google Drive folder

Answer (score 0):

You need to click `Change` on the print dialog under destination. Select `Save as PDF` for saving into local drive.

[image]